# how can i use Scala's for with index change?

Tags: java, scala

i got a problem in Scala's loop:
in java i can do this:

`for(int i=1;i<list.length;i=i*2`

but how could i do the same in scala?
Scala's for index cannot change

Comment: What index sequence do you expect to get? 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, or 0, 2, 4, 8, 16?

Comment: `i=i*2`? Since you're starting at `0` that means your index `i` is never changing.

Comment: What you posted is incomplete fragment of Java code, it is hard to guess what do you really want to achieve.

Comment: sorry,maybe i got a mistake,it start from 1

Comment: If you could post mode details of actual algorithm you implementing. It would really help. Thanks

Comment: yes,in fact ,im writing a Mergesort in Scala. I have written in java before,and i just want to do in scala

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scanLeft` method might be helpful there:

```scala
def exps(n: Int, p: Int) = (0 until n).scanLeft(1)((acc, _) => acc * p)

val list = List(2, 3, 5, 7)
for (i <- exps(list.size, 2)) println(i)
1
2
4
8
16
```

Or using infinite streams:

```scala
def expStream(p: Int, i: Int = 1): Stream[Int] = i #:: expStream(p, i * p)

for (i <- expStream(2).take(list.size)) println(i)
```

Also you can use `Stream.iterate` (which is somewhat more concise) as Gyro Gearless has suggested in their answer:

```scala
def expStream(p: Int) = Stream.iterate(1)(_ * p)
```

Comment: Upvoted since the poster wasn't clear on the original intention (i.e. Linear vs Exponential increment).

Comment: seems your scanleft easier

Answer (score 3):

An idiomatic way would be to create an Stream from the function "*2":

```
import Stream._
val potsOfTwo = Stream.iterate (1) (_ * 2).takeWhile (_ < 1000)
potsOfTwo.foreach { println _ }
```

scala> potsOfTwo.foreach { println _ }
1
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512

Answer (score 0):

Well. On practice I would probably go for next solution:

```
val m = 100
val r = (0 to m).map(x => if (x * 2 < m) x * 2 else  -1).filter(t => t != -1 )
println(r)
```

Here is documentation  and examples you need to look at.
I would suspect you looking for ranges:

```
val r = 1 to 10
r: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
   6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

scala> val r = 1 to 10 by 2
r: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range(1, 3, 5, 7, 9)

scala> val r = 1 to 10 by 3
r: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range(1, 4, 7, 10)
```

http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/sequence-comprehensions.html

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch02s09.html

Comment: i konw how to use "by",but i dont how to do with subtraction, multiplication and division

Comment: Well, i dont see how your .map will yield the desired result... 

scala> val m = 100
m: Int = 100

scala> val r = (1 to m).map(x => if (x * 2 < m) x * 2 else  0).filter(t => t != 0 )
r: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 4
2, 44, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 60, 62, 64, 66, 68, 70, 72, 74, 76, 78, 80, 82, 84, 86, 88, 90, 92, 94, 96, 98)

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: but i still have a question,doesnt it go more showly than java to do the same thing?

Comment: I am not sure about this specific example. But usually for pure scala code people use factor of 2 to compare java and scala performance. Obviously, scala will be a bit slower as it hosted on top of java.